# Visual Basic standalone executable

Tags: visual-studio

I have a very simple program written in Visual Basic in Visual Studio 2022. It's a single form with 4 text boxes with things like name, company, email and phone. When the only button is pressed it appends whatever is in those boxes to a *.csv file. It works great on my computer when I press F5.

If I put that executable on another computer it doesn't run at all. There's a dll file that's generated, when I put that dll along with the executable on another computer I get an error message: "You must install .NET Desktop Runtime to run this application. Architecture: x64, App host version: 6.0.7"

I would like this to be a standalone executable that will work on any Windows machine.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of just copying the executables to another machine, use the Publish feature and select the "self contained" option. For more info see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/)